# Apache serve mobile/desktop site depending on User-Agent same URL

Tags: apache, mobile, desktop, server

How to configure Apache so that it decides depending on client's User-Agent and then serves the right directory (mobile or desktop site) and the requirement is that both site MUST be served from the same url.

It means that both mobile and desktop sites are accessible from www.example.com. There will not be a m.example.com site.

Also, I don't want to use .htaccess but make changes directly in Apache configuration files.

tl;dr - If user goes to www.example.com with iPhone, he/she has to see mobile site and if user goes to www.exmaple.com with desktop computer, he/she has to see desktop site and NO URL REDIRECTIONS.

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your webserver. Read the user agent and serve stylesheets and other things accordingly

Comment: It has because I just don't want to serve different .css files, but different site with different backend in different directory on the server.

Comment: Usually it is done by having two different url like www.example.com + m.example.com but I would like those sites to use the same urls.